# Function return type syntax

Tags: c, function, syntax, dynamic-memory-allocation, return-type

In a function I am building a dynamically allocated 2D array. This array has a variable number of rows and a fixed number of columns (3). I would like to have this function return the array but I can't seem to get the operators precedence for the return type right.

The array has been defined as:

```
int (*refined_list)[3];
```

The attempts I have made up so far:

```
int (*)[3] funcName(int arg);
(int (*)[3]) funcName(int arg);
((int *)[3]) funcName(nt arg);
int ((*)[3]) funcName(int arg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

```
int (*funcName(int arg))[3];
```

The "thing" you want to declare goes inside the `(*)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way of doing that:

```
typedef int (*refined_list_type)[3];

refined_list_type funcName();
```